# Ajaxui tabs : Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tabs'

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, tabs

I am stuck :( I keep getting this error on my main html but works fine in the demo html, so maybe one of the files are calling for something that doesn't exist? I tried copying the js separately or just call them from their folder 'jqueryui' , nothing seems to work... anyone help please?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqueryui/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqueryui/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqueryui/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqueryui/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqueryui/ui/jquery.ui.tabs.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Morbi tincidunt</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis.</p>
        <p>Duis cursus. </p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure your `jqueryui/ui/jquery.ui.tabs.js` is loaded?

Comment: I can verify that the file exists, but I don't know how to check wether it successfully loaded or not

Comment: move jquery.ui.tabs.js just below the `jquery-1.9.1.js`

Comment: @Elijah View source your page, and click on the path your js files, and browser will attempt to load it, if the address is correct, the file will load, otherwise you get 404 error.

Comment: @nox: that's how I verified them yes, they all load. 
karthikr: tried it, same error :(

Answer (score 2):

`.tab()` function works on `jquery-1.8.2.js`. in newer versions, it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I simplified the above code and only included what I thought mattered. But found it out just now that I took out another instance of jquery before the body end tag! removing it made the script work.

Thanks for helping out